# Setting Windows Compatibility when creating multiple certificate templates using powershell and xml

Tags: xml, powershell, windows-server-2016, certificate-authority

I can currently create multiple certificate templates using a powershell script and an xml file with some details, however I cannot currently set the Compatibility for the CA or Certificate Recipient, they remain at 2003/XP regardless.

Is it possible to update these config items using this current method?

[image]

The Powershell script I am using is this (yes, I know I've got it spelt Temaplate in places):

```
Param($nameList,$configModel)

$Domain = $configModel.UserDomain
$CAConfigStr = "{0}\{1}" -f $configModel.CAServer.IP, $configModel.CAName
$TemplatesFile = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path.Replace(".ps1",".xml")

function Main($CAConfigStr, $TemplatesFile)
{
    $ImportBytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($TemplatesFile)
    $CEP = New-Object -ComObject X509enrollment.CX509EnrollmentPolicyWebService
    $CEP.InitializeImport($ImportBytes)
    $CEP.GetTemplates()|%{$_}|%{
        $ADWritable = New-Object -ComObject X509Enrollment.CX509CertificateTemplateADWritable
        $ADWritable.Initialize($_); $TemaplateName = $ADWritable.Property(1)
        
        $ConfigContext = ([ADSI]"LDAP://RootDSE").ConfigurationNamingContext
        $LDAPPath = "LDAP://CN=$TemaplateName,CN=Certificate Templates,CN=Public Key Services,CN=Services,$ConfigContext"
        if(![ADSI]::Exists($LDAPPath)){
            $ADWritable.Commit(1,$null); while(-not [ADSI]::Exists($LDAPPath)){sleep 5}
        }
                    
        $CertAdmin = New-Object -ComObject CertificateAuthority.Admin
        $Templates = $CertAdmin.GetCAProperty($CAConfigStr,29,0,4,0)
        $Templates += $TemaplateName + "`n" + $ADWritable.Property(12).Value + "`n"
        $CertAdmin.SetCAProperty($CAConfigStr, 29, 0, 4, $Templates);

        Assign-CertificateTemplatePermission $Domain $TemaplateName 
    }
}

function Set-CertificateTemplateSecurity($TemaplateName, $User, $Permission)
{
    [string[]]$Rights = $null
    [string[]]$Permission = $Permission.Replace(' ','').Split(',')
    
    if($Permission -contains "FullControl"){
        $Rights += "GenericAll"
    }
    else{
        if($Permission -contains "Read"){$Rights += "ReadProperty, GenericExecute"}
        if($Permission -contains "Write"){$Rights += "WriteProperty, WriteDacl, WriteOwner"}
        if($Permission -contains "Enroll" -and $Permission -contains "AutoEnroll"){$Rights += "ExtendedRight"}
    }

    $ConfigContext = ([ADSI]"LDAP://RootDSE").ConfigurationNamingContext
    $ADSI = [ADSI]"LDAP://CN=$TemaplateName,CN=Certificate Templates,CN=Public Key Services,CN=Services,$ConfigContext"

    $NTAccount = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount($User)
    $IdentityReference = $NTAccount.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier])

    if($Rights){
        $ACE = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryAccessRule($IdentityReference, ($Rights -join ','),"Allow")
        $ADSI.psbase.ObjectSecurity.SetAccessRule($ACE)
    }

    if($Permission -contains "Enroll" -and $Permission -notmatch "AutoEnroll"){
        $ACE = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryAccessRule($IdentityReference,"ExtendedRight","Allow",[GUID]"0e10c968-78fb-11d2-90d4-00c04f79dc55")
        $ADSI.psbase.ObjectSecurity.AddAccessRule($ACE)
    }
    elseif($Permission -notcontains "Enroll" -and $Permission -match "AutoEnroll"){
        $ACE = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryAccessRule($IdentityReference,"ExtendedRight","Allow",[GUID]"a05b8cc2-17bc-4802-a710-e7c15ab866a2")
        $ADSI.psbase.ObjectSecurity.AddAccessRule($ACE)
    }

    $ADSI.psbase.commitchanges()
}

function Assign-CertificateTemplatePermission($Domain, $TemaplateName)
{
    switch -Wildcard ($TemaplateName)
    {
        "SAT*"
        {
            "$Domain\Domain Admins","$Domain\Administrator","$Domain\Enterprise Admins","$Domain\scepservice"|%{Set-CertificateTemplateSecurity $TemaplateName $_ "FullControl"}
            "NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users","$Domain\Domain Computers","$Domain\causer"|%{Set-CertificateTemplateSecurity $TemaplateName $_ "Read,Enroll"}
            break
        }

        "Client"
        {
            "$Domain\Domain Admins","$Domain\Administrator","$Domain\Enterprise Admins","$Domain\scepservice"|%{Set-CertificateTemplateSecurity $TemaplateName $_ "FullControl"}
            "NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users","$Domain\Domain Computers"|%{Set-CertificateTemplateSecurity $TemaplateName $_ "Read,Enroll"}
            break
        }

        "*V2"
        {
            "$Domain\Domain Admins","$Domain\Administrator","$Domain\Enterprise Admins","$Domain\scepservice"|%{Set-CertificateTemplateSecurity $TemaplateName $_ "FullControl"}
            "NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users"|%{Set-CertificateTemplateSecurity $TemaplateName $_ "Read,Enroll"}
        }

        "ThirdPartyVendors" 
        {
            "$Domain\Domain Admins","$Domain\Administrator","$Domain\Enterprise Admins"|%{Set-CertificateTemplateSecurity $TemaplateName $_ "FullControl"}
            "NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users","$Domain\Domain Computers","$Domain\causer"|%{Set-CertificateTemplateSecurity $TemaplateName $_ "Read,Enroll"}
        }

        "EGMap"
        {
            "$Domain\Domain Admins","$Domain\Administrator","$Domain\Enterprise Admins"|%{Set-CertificateTemplateSecurity $TemaplateName $_ "FullControl"}
            "NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users","$Domain\Domain Computers"|%{Set-CertificateTemplateSecurity $TemaplateName $_ "Read,Enroll"}
            "$Domain\scepservice"|%{Set-CertificateTemplateSecurity $TemaplateName $_ "Read,Enroll,AutoEnroll"}
        }

        "UIIntegration"
        {
            "$Domain\Domain Computers"|%{Set-CertificateTemplateSecurity $TemaplateName $_ "Enroll"}
        }
    }
}

Main $CAConfigStr $TemplatesFile
@{"IsSucceeded"="true";"ErrorMsg"=""}
```

And an excerp of the XML file I have is thus:

```
<GetPoliciesResponse xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/pki/2009/01/enrollmentpolicy">
  <response>
    <policyID/>
    <policyFriendlyName/>
    <nextUpdateHours>8</nextUpdateHours>
    <policiesNotChanged a:nil="true" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
    <policies>
      <policy>
        <policyOIDReference>5</policyOIDReference>
        <cAs>
          <cAReference>0</cAReference>
        </cAs>
        <attributes>
          <commonName>CEPEncryptionV2</commonName>
          <policySchema>2</policySchema>
          <certificateValidity>
            <validityPeriodSeconds>473040000</validityPeriodSeconds>
            <renewalPeriodSeconds>220752000</renewalPeriodSeconds>
          </certificateValidity>
          <permission>
            <enroll>true</enroll>
            <autoEnroll>true</autoEnroll>
          </permission>
          <privateKeyAttributes>
            <minimalKeyLength>2048</minimalKeyLength>
            <keySpec>1</keySpec>
            <keyUsageProperty a:nil="true" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
            <permissions a:nil="true" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
            <algorithmOIDReference a:nil="true" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
            <cryptoProviders>
              <provider>Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider</provider>
            </cryptoProviders>
          </privateKeyAttributes>
          <revision>
            <majorRevision>100</majorRevision>
            <minorRevision>2</minorRevision>
          </revision>
          <supersededPolicies a:nil="true" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
          <privateKeyFlags>16</privateKeyFlags>
          <subjectNameFlags>9</subjectNameFlags>
          <enrollmentFlags>8</enrollmentFlags>
          <generalFlags>131649</generalFlags>
          <hashAlgorithmOIDReference a:nil="true" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
          <rARequirements a:nil="true" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
          <keyArchivalAttributes a:nil="true" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
          <extensions>
            <extension>
              <oIDReference>7</oIDReference>
              <critical>false</critical>
              <value>MC0GJSsGAQQBgjcVCISYgHiBgJAMgYmLLOeTW4GirGZohtKkE4SgyncCAWQCAQM=</value>
            </extension>
            <extension>
              <oIDReference>8</oIDReference>
              <critical>false</critical>
              <value>MAwGCisGAQQBgjcUAgE=</value>
            </extension>
            <extension>
              <oIDReference>9</oIDReference>
              <critical>true</critical>
              <value>AwIFIA==</value>
            </extension>
            <extension>
              <oIDReference>10</oIDReference>
              <critical>false</critical>
              <value>MA4wDAYKKwYBBAGCNxQCAQ==</value>
            </extension>
          </extensions>
        </attributes>
</policy>
```

I'm DREADFUL at asking these questions so will have invariably missed something, please shout at me when you need more info.

Thanks a million in advance.

Comment: See : https://msendpointmgr.com/2020/06/15/how-to-renew-ndes-service-certificates-for-usage-with-microsoft-intune/